# How can I root the GT 10.1 (running 3.2)?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rooting Samsung Tablet GT--P7510 Android 3.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18243/rooting-samsung-tablet-gt-p7510-android-3-2)

I've tried using Odin to get root access, but when I finish the process, I still don't have root privileges. Seems like all the tutorials about how to root are assuming the tab is running 3.1 or lower... did the update to 3.2 break the root methods? If so, how can I root this darn thing? ;)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With 3.2 Google fixed the exploit that allowed most current methods to gain root on 3.1 version.  The only way to get root on Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2 is to flash a pre-rooted ROM via Odin (or Heimdal) utility.  Take a look at the appropriate section on [XDA-Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1053) for more details.

This completely wipes all data off the device, so it's recommended to back up anything you need first.  Also, be sure to pick the correct ROM for your specific version of the Tab, since 
different versions (WiFi-only Vs. 3G) will require separate ROMs.