# Is there any way to root the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

Is there any way to root the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1? I found some instructions on [rooting the 7 inch version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2391367) but I'm not sure if that matters. Also the instructions include flashing UK firmware. I'd prefer to do as little changes to my device as possible so I can get a backup as close to the way it came as possible.

Comment: Have you looked at [How can I root the Galaxy Tab 10.1?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18243/16575)

Comment: @Izzy that's not the tab 3 :-)

Comment: Well, it's a Tab 10.1 with Android 3 #D OK, already thought so, but was not 100% sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions are pretty hard to follow but should work: [root insntructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432467)